# Laravel DB query to array

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, object, type-conversion

I stored "hello,world" in a mysql database as an array and then tried to retrieve using below query

```
 @php
    $post_id = $post->id;
    $result= DB::table('posts')
    ->select('tags')
    ->where('id', '=',  $post_id)
    ->get();

    echo($result);

 @endphp
```

The echoed result is:

```
[{"tags":"hello,world"}]
```

I need to echo single values for above result

```
hello 

world
```

Comment: This is explained in the Laravel documentation under "Running a select query" https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries

Comment: i checked but cant find any solution

Comment: It's literally there: "The select method will always return an array of results. Each result within the array will be a PHP StdClass object, allowing you to access the values of the results."

Comment: Can u help me with that using foreach or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@php
    $post_id = $post->id;
    $result= DB::table('posts')
    ->select('tags')
    ->where('id', '=',  $post_id)
    ->first();

  $tags = $results->tags;
  $tagsArray =  explode(',', $tags);
 @endphp
```

and now

```
@foreach($tagsArray as $ta)
{{ $ta }} <br />

@endforeach
```

Your output will be

> hello
>
> world

Answer (score 0):

```
@php
$post_id = $post->id;
$result= DB::table('posts')
              ->select('tags')
              ->where('id', '=',  $post_id)
              ->get();

echo($result[0]->tags);
@endphp
```

**This code will give you output:**

```
hello,world
```

You can use string **split()** function, check the function manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php)